# GAE/Maven error on clean install Plugin "com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.18 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved"

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, pom.xml, artifact

I am really struggling to get going with Google App Engine as the setup for the Cloud Endpoints tutorial is not going as smoothly as I'd expected.

[The tutorial I am trying to follow](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/hello_world)

The issue arises after I have created the MyBean.java and YourFirstAPI.java, navigated to the folder containing pom.xml and run "mvn clean install". This error happens:

```
[ERROR] Plugin com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.18 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:jar:1.9.18 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

[The help article suggested](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException)

I have tried reinstalling maven, and I have tried running "mvn clean install -U" but it hasn't helped.

This is the result of running mvn -version

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T21:58:10+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_67, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Believe it or not I'm not a complete novice and have used GAE on an internship before, but getting it setup on my own computer is proving to be a nightmare. I've been tearing my hair our over this for a long time now so any suggestions at all would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, despite what the tutorial says or what Maven generates via the archetype plugin there's no version 1.9.18 of the appengine-maven-plugin at the moment. Try switching to the previous version, 1.9.17, in your POM. Also change the version numbers from 1.9.18 to 1.9.17 in the dependencies as well.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks very much. Any idea why the wrong version is in the tutorials? Is it just a mistake?

Comment: @Eden Looks like the plugin was just lagging a bit behind the SDK itself. Version 1.9.18 was finally released a short while ago.